# Castle Windsor ProxyGenerationException

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, aop, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm getting the following error trying to proxy an Interface (without target) that implements two different generic forms of the same generic interface.

So, I have:

```
public interface IGenericFoo<T> 
{
    void DoSomething<T>();
}

// this is the interface I'm trying to proxy without target
public interface IFoo : IGenericFoo<MyType1>, IGenericFoo<MyType2>
{
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Duplicate element: Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.MetaMethod

at DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithoutTarget
```

Any suggestions? Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: looks like a bug unsupported scenario in DynamicProxy. Please submit an issue to issue tracker.

Comment: Slightly related - if I add an OnCreate handler to a interface without target component, the instance comes across as null to the handler. Is this by design? Thanks.

Comment: Any thoughts on where I might look if I want to see about fixing this myself? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this? I'm encountering this issue on a class which implements `IEnumerable<TItem>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem>>`.